# div not getting contained when floated -

Tags: css, css-float

Does anyone know why this .inner div isn't containing this element that is floating right?

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/7Sunw/)

```
<header>
    <div class="inner">

        <h1>Heading Level 1</h1>

        <h2>Heading Level 2</h2>

        <a href="http://derekthomaswood.com">BUTTON</a>

    </div> <!-- end .inner -->
</header>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `overflow: auto` to `.inner`: http://jsfiddle.net/7Sunw/1/

`float: left/right` takes element somehow out of standard elements flow, so parent elements no longer stretches to it's size. You have to use `overflow: auto` to make it happen even if children elements are floated.

Comment: Yep. Could you elaborate on this at all? I haven't really needed the overflow auto before in this case. What specifically is prompting the need? How is the floated link breaking the flow?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a little bit of explanation. Hope it helped.

Comment: While it doesn't really answer the question, "why" - I'm gonna mark this as solved. Thanks for your help! That did the trick! If I find some stuff in the spec, I'll throw it up here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add another div after header

```
<div id="footer" style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Should do it

Comment: Well, while that may work, my question was a "why" question not really a how question - and I don't want to just add an div to my markup.